# Nexus 5 Dark Photos Android Camera

Tags: android, camera

When taking photos with Nexus 5, there seems to be an auto exposure adjustment taking place every time either the .autofocus or .takepicture commands are called.

This sometimes results (1 in 4 photos) with the shutter being called mid exposure adjusmtment resulting in dark photos.

It also means the camera operation is much slower than desirable. This does not happen on the stock camera app.

The only api I can see to change this behaviour is parameters.setAutoExposureLock which prevents auto exposure adjustment but it has the problem of locking the exposure on a (usually) dark setting and preventing any manual adjustment using calls to setExposureCompensation.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

make sure that you set the recording hint on

```
Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();    
p.setRecordingHint(true);
mCamera.setParameters(p);
```

in Nexus 5 it solves many issues